# How to Count Number of Cards in a CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

I have a `JPanel` which uses a `CardLayout` to have a number of pages, and to make a progress bar that fills up as pages are defined, I would like to count the number of cards added to my `CardLayout`. Is there a way of counting cards programatically, or will I have to track the number of pages with a variable?

Comment: Have you tried `getComponentCount` on the base component (using the `CardLayout`)?  Remember, the container still holds all the components, the layout just manages them

Comment: That has worked, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the cards are the only components that the `JPanel` holds, then indeed `getComponentCount()` returns the number of pages.